Fetch Data From Website - Custom Theme Development
I am developing a custom WordPress theme focused on Anime/Drama. I need to create a function in the admin panel that can fetch data from a URL, such as post categories, titles, etc. I’m not a professional developer, so I would appreciate a detailed and beginner-friendly guide on how to achieve this. Thank you!
Here the Image What I want to say: Image

look the diagram on this page : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/templates/template-hierarchy/. e.g. for formatting post categories, you have archive.html for all categories (all taxinomies) or category.html just for post categories.

you can use Php scraping libraries like html dom, curl, guzzle and much more, also can search YouTube,

After scraping list categories using this WordPress built in
function get_categories() check sample code here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

And then insert post if you want using wp_insert_post() function see
code details here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Before submit post validate category using this WordPress function
category_exist() with if else statement function use reference here
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/category_exists/


see functions details from provided link by click on (User Contributed
Notes) on right side of page.
